# Using xvfb-run shell command in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I want to use a node script that uses a xvfb (virtual X server). I have this command:

```
xvfb-run -a --server-args="-screen 0 1366x768x24" node something.js
```

which works in the terminal. But when I try to rewrite it to the Elixir:

```ruby
System.cmd "xvfb-run", ["-a", "--server-args=\"-screen 0 
1366x768x24\"", "node", "something.js"]
```

then I have error which is saying that I need xvfb. It's the same error that I get when I run just `node something.js`.

I tried [Porcelain](https://github.com/alco/porcelain):

```ruby
Porcelain.exec "xvfb-run", ["-a", "--server-args=\"-screen 0 
1366x768x24\"", "node", "something.js"]
```

but it has the same problem. Maybe I'm not using it properly?

I also tried an erlang's `os` lib:

```ruby
"xvfb-run -a --server-args=\"-screen 0 1366x768x24\" node something.js"
|> String.to_charlist
|> :os.cmd
|> to_string
```

which works better, it doesn't have the xvfb problem, but it get stuck in middle of script without any warnings. The command is not terminating, the node script is just not going further.

I know that I can write small .sh script for that. But it would be nice to get this work in plain Elixir

Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Try removing both the `\"` from the second argument (i.e. make it `"--server-args=-screen 0 
1366x768x24"`). They should not be there when invoking a command with a list of arguments like this.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to `"--server-args=-screen\ 0\ 1366x768x24"` and now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with `"`. I have changed the argument

```
"--server-args=\"-screen 0 1366x768x24\""
```

to

```
"--server-args=-screen\ 0\ 1366x768x24"
```

and now it works